# Is many consoles in securetty file a risk?

Tags: linux, rhel, security, console

I got a problem So I expect you can give me an answer.
I have to evaluate the security of a RedHat server. The idea is review the /etc/securetty file to ensure that only the console tty is listed. But I've found the following:

```
====================================================
[FILE]: SECURETTY
-rw------- 1 root root 122 Feb 17  2003 /etc/securetty
====================================================
console
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
vc/10
vc/11
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
tty10
tty11
=================================
```

Why are these many consoles? Is this a risk?

Comment: "Risk" is a relative term. It depends on your current set up and what else you have going on in your network and how you have services configured. SSH typically allocates a `pty` terminal so the above would prevent someone from a network connection ever becoming root. If you've already denied root access via ssh and sudo/su, though, this point is moot. I don't really see many ways these tty's could become an issue though.

Answer (score 3):

They're all local consoles.

`/dev/console` is the system console, `/dev/vc/N` and `/dev/ttyN` are both virtual consoles. On machines with remote management (or lack a framebuffer console), you'll likely also see one or more ttyS* entries in there to allow logging in via serial connections.

They're there to allow root to login via the system console. If you remove them, root won't be able to do that which may hurt your chances of fixing issues with the system.

Conversely, once a malicious person obtains physical access to the console of the machine, whether or not root can login via the console is moot. The security of the system has already been compromised. Think sledgehammer, yanking out cables, stealing disks, or just rebooting using a rescue disk and accessing everything.

By the way, this is all pretty trivial to find out by reading the manpages for tty, console, etc., or searching online. The Linux (i.e. kernel) documentation is pretty explanatory, as well. You should definitely get some experience in this stuff before performing security audits.